# setMaximumSize not working in java

Tags: java, jframe

I hava a java program with a JFrame

I am using absolute positioning

here is my main function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ape Ape = new ape();
    Ape.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Ape.setSize(1000,1000);
    Ape.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
    Ape.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
    Ape.setVisible(true);
}
```

When I run the program I try to resize it and make the window smaller but I can't

when I try to make the window bigger it works fine I basicly skips the `setMaximumSize()` function

I have read around and aparently this has happened before

is this a known bug?

if so I heard I could make a Window Listener, when I tried it I implemented the functions that WindowListener needed but could not find anything to solve my problem

please try this yourself and see what happens...

thanks in advance

PS... please don't laugh about the names I give my classes... :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

see http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5342801:

It's a known bug:

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;?bug_id=6200438
- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4744281
- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4320050

Maybe you could use

```
Ape.setResizable(false)
```

instead?

PS: It's a convention to give classes names that start with a capital letter and variables ones with a small letter, not vice versa.

Comment: thanks for the report and the Ape.setResizable is basicly what I wanted thanks

Comment: I am searching if this bug is resolved. I am using jdk1.6.0_45 (App was developed years ago and I am maintaining it). Is it still a bug?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used the following and it worked:

```
    Dimension newDim = new Dimension(width, height);

    label.setMinimumSize(newDim);
    label.setPreferredSize(newDim);
    label.setMaximumSize(newDim);
    label.setSize(newDim);
    label.revalidate();
```

Comment: I don't know how to say thanks to you .. thankyou thankyou so much. You saved my face and day. revalidate is the key.

Answer (score 1):

For Netbeans user try to set values for the maximum frame in setMaximizedBounds() click in properties of frame you will find an option to define values for setMaximizedBounds.

Comment: This 2-year-old reply helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this :

```
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1480, 910);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1200, 799));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1480, 910));
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1480, 910));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            double w = frame.getSize().getWidth();
            double h = frame.getSize().getHeight();
            if(w > 1480.0 && h > 910.0){
                frame.setSize(new Dimension(1480, 910));
                frame.repaint();
                frame.revalidate();
            }

            super.componentResized(e);
        }

    });
```