# Java swing setMaximumSize not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setMaximumSize not working in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061010/setmaximumsize-not-working-in-java)

I've having trouble with my `JFrame` subclass. I need to set a Maximum height.

But `setMaximumSize` does not work. It seems that's a bug in java (setMinimumSize works). How could prevent a `JFrame` from getting higher than a given height ?

Comment: Well. I use setMaximumSize on my JFrame. But I still can enlarge the JFrame above the limits I set.

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061010/setmaximumsize-not-working-in-java

Comment: Yup, I already saw this page. But there isn't a solution for my problem :)

Comment: It does work though I have working examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead/as well:

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

In my experience `setPreferredSize(Dimension)` takes preference and always works.

I usually use all of them anyway: `setMinimumSize()`, `setMaximumSize()`, `setPreferredSize()`
and then `setSize()` as well

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, setMinimumSize and setMaximumSize are not reliable - they may work in some situations, but often not in others

The best solution is to use a ComponentListener, implement componentResized, and enforce the min / max size that way

Comment: +1 See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? How would you enforce the min/max size by catching resize events? AFAIK these events are fired as notifications and wouldn't be helpful in enforcing size limits.