# JSplitPane -- can't set maximum size;

Tags: java, swing, resize, jsplitpane

Been a while since I've been here.  I'm learning java and have a question as to why the panel I've created in a JSplitPane can be resized beyond the maximum that I've set:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class MainWindow {
 
 
//set all components
 

 

JFrame frame;
JPanel showPanel;//displays individual contact when clicked on in the contacts panel;
JPanel listPanel;// displays the contactsPanel
    JSplitPane contactsSplitPane;
             
public void buildMainWindow() {// open method       
     
    frame = new JFrame("Contacts");
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     
    showPanel = new JPanel();
            showPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            
            listPanel = new JPanel();
            listPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            listPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension (300,1000));
            
            
            //create SplitPane for the listPanel and showPanel
    contactsSplitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, listPanel,showPanel);
    contactsSplitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    contactsSplitPane.setDividerLocation(50);   
         
    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);    
    frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, contactsSplitPane);
 }//close method
 
public static void main (String [] args) {
    MainWindow MainWindow = new MainWindow ();
    MainWindow.buildMainWindow();
}
 
}// close class
```

feel free to run and compile.  I've set the size of the listPanel to a maximum of 300 pixels, but I can resize it way beyond that -- almost to the end of the frame.  It's not possible to crate a single resizable pane, no?

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?  I'm obviously missing something, but I don't know what.

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157954/java-swing-setmaximumsize-not-working which deals with a JFrame, not a JSplitPane. I reopened the question so we can have answers related to a JSplitPane.

Answer (score 1):

A `JSplitPane` doesn't respect the maximum size of either component.

However, it does respect the minimum size of a component.

So one approach could be do set the minimum size on the other component added to the split pane. You will need to override the `getMinimumSize()` method of this component since the size of the split pane can change dynamically.

Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SplitPaneMaximum extends JPanel
{
    JSplitPane splitPane;

    public SplitPaneMaximum()
    {

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JPanel red = new JPanel();
        red.setBackground( Color.RED );
        red.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200, 100) );
        red.setMinimumSize( new Dimension(100, 0) );

        JPanel blue = new JPanel()
        {
            //  Setting a minimum size here will limit the maximum size
            //  of the other component added to the split pane

            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize()
            {
                int parentWidth = getParent().getSize().width;
                Dimension d = getSize();
                d.width = parentWidth - 200;

                return d;
            }
        };

        blue.setBackground( Color.BLUE );
        blue.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200, 100) );

        splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        splitPane.setLeftComponent( red );
        splitPane.setRightComponent( blue );
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.50);
        add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SplitPaneMaximum");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new SplitPaneMaximum() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now the width of the red panel can only be sized between 100 and 200 pixels.

Comment: Okay -- so then why is there a setMaximumSize() method at all if it's not respected?

Comment: The size methods are only hints for the layout manager.  It is up to the layout manager to determine if it wants to use/ignore the size hints. I would guess the internal layout manager of the JSplitPane was written to only respect the preferred and minimum sizes.